# From structure to message

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

Does someone has ideas about how to directly send a C structure over topics/services/actions ?
Currently I read some data from a file and end up with this data in a structure S, then I copy the data in S into a ROS msg data structure ROS_S (which is identical to S).
This copy-past step bothers me and I would like to know if someone has a simple solution about this.

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11828/from-structure-to-message/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To avoid the extra step of converting from S to ROS_S on the publisher, you can define custom serialization functions for S.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-11-07**:
This should work quit fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If they're actually identical you could just use ROS_S instead of S the first time.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-11-07**:
Indeed it would be simpler. However I don't have control on the first reading step (from data to S) so I can't read the data and put it directly in ROS_S.